# series and lim sup proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

if $∑|a_n|$ is convergent and for all n $ |\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}|\le|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$. (1)
 prove $∑|b_n|$ is convergent.
My answer is :
since $∑|a_n|$ is convergent, then $∑a_n$ is convergent. so it must have met the ratio test, so
$\lim \sup |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|<1$
from (1) we conclude $ |\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}|<1$ as well. which means $∑b_n$ also meets the ratio test. hence it is absolutely convergent, so $∑|b_n|$ is convergent too.
I am confused with lim sup thing. can I say 
since $ |\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}|\le|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ then 
$\lim \sup |\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}| \le \lim \sup |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ ( if yes, what is the proof for that? I know such proof for just limit ) Thanks

Comment: Note $\sum 1/n^2<\infty$ but the ratios $\to 1.$

Comment: You *can* say that $\limsup\left\lvert\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\right\rvert\le \limsup\left\lvert\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\rvert$, of course, but your argument crumbles nonetheless because you *cannot* say that $\limsup\left\lvert\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\rvert<1$: rather, you *must* deal with the fact that $\limsup\left\lvert\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\right\rvert=\limsup\left\lvert\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\rvert= 1$ is a possibility.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments your proof is not correct.

Let $c_n=\frac {|a_{n+1}|} {|a_n|}$. Then $|b_{n+1}|\leq |c_n |b_n|$ from this you get $|b_n| \leq c_1c_2...c_{n-1} |b_1|=\frac {|a_n| } {|a_1|} |b_1|$ and hence $\sum |b_n| <\infty$.

Comment: It might be easier to just write

$$\frac{|b_{n+1}|}{|b_n|}\frac{|b_{n}|}{|b_{n-1}|}\cdots \frac{|b_2|}{|b_1|} \le \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\frac{|a_{n}|}{|a_{n-1}|}\cdots \frac{|a_2|}{|a_1|}$$

which implies $|b_{n+1}|\le (|b_1|/|a_1|)|a_{n+1}|.$

Answer (score 0):

For convenience of notation, we can assume, without loss of generality, that $a_n,b_n > 0$, for all $n$.

With that assumption, suppose
$$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \le \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$
for all $n$, and suppose $\sum a_n$ converges.

**Claim:**$\;\sum b_n$ converges.

**Proof:**$\;$Rearranging the given inequality, we get
$$\frac{b_{n+1}}{a_{n+1}} \le \frac{b_n}{a_n}$$
for all $n$.

It follows that
$$\frac{b_n}{a_n} \le \frac{b_1}{a_1}$$
for all $n$.

Thus, letting $c={\large{\frac{b_1}{a_1}}}$, we have $b_n\le ca_n$, for all $n$.

Hence, since $\sum ca_n$ converges, so does $\sum b_n$, as was to be shown.

Comment: Thank you very much. such clean proof.